# ASP.NET button click causes duplicate events IE10/Win7HomePremium

Tags: asp.net, button, click

Just surveying to get an idea if anyone has came across this before. I have narrowed down the issue to a local machine running Win7HomePremium with IE10, it's a report that when the user clicks the "Printer Friendly" button, the event occurs twice, within .03 time frame. Sometimes the timestamps come back as 12:00:00am when the click occurs during the day also. Has anyone had any issues with click events and what steps did you take to resolve the issue.

I can't duplicate it on any other machine in our office, and the client can't duplicate it on any other machines in house either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As crazy as it seems, the resolution was to force IE10 to render Doc Mode as IE5 Quirks. The app is dated around 1999 and uses many placeholders within placeholders, tables within tables which already causes it to render in Quirks for any version of IE. For whatever reason using IE5Quirks fixed the duplicate entry into the DB on the event.

Comment: javascript was disabling the button which was the root cause. The fix I used was placing a css disabled class on the button during processing. Issue solved